# Removing a Section from Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know you can use `<remove />` to remove keys.  I tried to use that though for a section in my web.config, I guess that you can't remove sections?  And what if I wanted to remove the entire group "webServices" ??

```
<sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <remove section="jsonSerialization" />
    <remove section="profileService" />
    <remove section="authenticationService" />
    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

IIS is throwing a fit about the above starting with this error message:

`The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

It's talking about the section above starting with the jsonSerialization and subsequent sections in that group.

Comment: You can use *what* to remove keys?

Comment: @Henk : I'm guessing he doesn't mean a text editor.

Comment: <remove> tag removes whatever in the web.config.  <remove name="somemodule" /> works but I want to remove the sections above, they are not modules

Comment: Take a look in the event log to see if there's more detail. These exceptions usually have InnerExceptions with more detail. I think you have a version issue. Maybe an ASP.NET 2.0 site inheriting from a 3.5 site.

Answer (score 2):

`<section/>` only defines the type that corresponds to the section. It does not add the section itself. So why do you want to remove the section?

---

BTW, `<remove/>` only works for certain collections. These are the ones that have

```
<add/>
<remove/>
<clear/>
```

Comment: I am getting web.config inheritance problems from parent and need to remove the conflicting sections that IIS is throwing a fit about.

Comment: Please edit your question with the specific, narrowed-down example. Is this a 3.5 vs. 2.0 issue?

Comment: what's the actual error you're getting for the conflicting sections?  If it's related to collections of <add/> collections (outside of sections), add a <clear/> at the top of each collection.

Comment: see updated post.  I tried adding clear inside the SectionGroup (right after the first SectionGroup tag but it's not a tag that it recognizes.